# Query fetched some unauthorised data: Filter or block

Tags: rest, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring-data-rest but this can be general question. If I am creating a REST service and the authenticated user makes a REST query which fetched some data that is unauthorised, should the response be 403 or should I filter out the data that is unauthorised and send the rest.

Another case could be such that the user requests data is completely unauthorised. In such a case, should the response be 403 or 404?

Answer (score 1):

For GET I use 404 and filtering.
If the response is a set of entities then I simply filter out the ones the current user has no READ permission to. (If all of the data is filtered out the request is an empty set, but it's still OK.)
If the response is one entity and the user has no READ permission to it, then I return 404.

IMHO, if the user has no READ permission then he shouldn't even know about the existence of the entity. (If I return 403, then he will know that there is an object with that id.)

I only return 403 if the user has READ, but no UPDATE/DELETE permission and he tries to manipulate the data.

Also, if he tries to delete multiple objects, then I delete only those he has DELETE permission to, and silently skip the rest.

I created [Spring-Data-Rest ACL extension](https://github.com/BerryCloud/spring-data-jpa-acl/tree/master/acl) which handles all of these issues automatically on all auto-generated endpoints (+ a lot more) if you are interested in.